Drupal 10.3.1 : Mulilingual views header and footer
I'm runnig a Drupal 10 site on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS with ph. 8.3.10
Could someone please give me a hint how to translate title, header and footer of a view?
Everything works fine in my multilingual installation: Nodes, menues, paths, even the nodes listed by the view show up prperly according to the selected language.
The translations of the view header and footer are saved... I can access them via regional & languages => configuration translation or directly from within view. But the don't show up elsewhere - not in the view preview and not on the frontend.
Any idea what am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks a lot and best regards

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
